# How do I bookmark a favorite user

Tags: discussion, feature-request, profile-page

I like to store some user profiles for future reference when I have time to look at their CV, when there any vacancy in my team.

Is there any way I can create list of favorite users that can be easily accessed from anywhere?

It is okay if I do not get any notification about user's activities, so I am not asking about "follow user" feature, my question is about much simple use case.

Comment: I just edited the question, do you still think it is duplicate?

Answer (score 1):

> I like to store some user profiles for future reference when I have time to look at their CV

Your browser has a "bookmarks" feature (although it might use a different name for it, like "favorites," just in the interest of being different). No matter what it is called, this is a perfectly reasonable use of that feature. It will even allow you to organize the profiles into folders, say, by area of expertise.

> when there any vacancy in my team.

Be advised that not everyone here is looking for a job. It might work best to just go to the Careers site when you have a vacancy and look for experts that are interested in job openings. The same people will be listed there that you would otherwise find on the site, but you would avoid the false positives of experts who are not interested.

> Is there any way I can create list of favorite users that can be easily accessed from anywhere?

Again, bookmarks. Many modern browsers now allow you to sync your bookmarks with "the cloud" so that you can access them from anywhere, including mobile devices. I see no compelling reason why this should be integrated with the site.

If it *were* to ever be integrated with the site, surely it should be a feature of Careers/Jobs/whatever they're calling it nowadays, since it has absolutely nothing to do with Q&A.

Comment: Thanks. I do not want to use browser sync because it mixes my personal bookmarks with office work.

Comment: You can create a separate folder for that, or perhaps a separate user profile within your browser. Or use your browser at home. Or at work. Or wherever you want these things to be stored. I'm not really sure how that's unique to the browser—you use the same Stack Overflow account at work and at home, too.